# Time Report by Categories instead of by Files

Tags: org-mode

In the org-mode time report (activated with R in the org-agenda view), the times are summed by file. 
Is there a way (or inconvenient) to sum it further by categories?

Summing up the time by file is practical for people who have few files in the agenda (e.g. self.org, people.org, academia.org, salary.org), but impractical for people who gather everything in one single org-file (it seems the case of many people who describe their configuration on the Internet), or for people who have many org-files (my case so far, and from a few other people in discussions).  An extension of this system, which would make reports available to all, would be to sum the time by categories (e.g. #+CATEGORY in file headers). It would be coherent with the way the #+CATEGORY info is already replacing file names in the agenda view, allowing tasks from distinct files to be sorted together when sorted by category.

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 and Org-mode version 7.9.3d.